# jQuery xhtml dd dl dt

Tags: jquery, html, xhtml

As it is user had to click on the same dt twice to hide its child element, how can I make it so it hides once any other dt is clicked.
Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#faq').find('dd').hide().end().find('dt').click(function () {
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>

<dl id="faq">
    <dt>Question 1?</dt>
    <dd>
        Weee look at me I can type!!!
    </dd>

    <dt>Question 2?</dt>
    <dd>
        Weee look at me I can type too!!!
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want only one `dd` to show at a time, and post this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#faq').find('dd').hide().end().find('dt').click(function () {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        $(this).siblings('dd').not($(this).next()).slideUp();
    });
});
```

- `$(this).next().slideDown();` slides down the next element, which is a `dd` element, and slides it *down*.
- `$(this).siblings('dd').not($(this).next()).slideUp();` slides *up* all other `dd` elements (the `.not($(this).next())` bit).

[`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) is what you're looking for, along with [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not).

[Demonstration JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tP3Zp/3/).

Comment: I had almost identical code O_o http://jsfiddle.net/baEUm/ I would still use slideToggle though instead of slideDown (oops... almost forgot... +1 XD)

Comment: @Joseph If we use `.slideToggle()`, either all elements will be shown, or no elements will be shown, making `.slideToggle()` impractical for this situation, hence why I used `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`.

Comment: @JamWaffles just look at the example I linked.  It works. :)  It just gives you the option of hiding the visible element rather than having it just stick there permanently. (i.e. you can go back to the original stsate).  Also, the order of the methods is important.

Comment: So it does - apologies. IMO, it's better to use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` because it tells both the DOM element and the programmer explicitly what to do/what's going on. Thanks for the +1

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWKWB/) of your code.

You can click on a `dt` to toggle it's "child" `dd`, but by the sounds of it, you want to hide all visible `dd`s when any `dt` is clicked.

You can do this by toggling all `dt` elements that are [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) next to the current `dd`:

```
$('#faq').find('dd').hide().end().find('dt').click(function () {
  $('#faq').find('dd:visible').not($(this).next()).slideToggle();
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Check out the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWKWB/1/).

You can compact the code slightly further by combining the first and second lines in the `click` callback, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wWKWB/2/).

Comment: The OP meant sibling elements - that is, elements _next to_ the clicked element, not _inside it_. Just wanted to clear things up.

Comment: Hence the quotes around child. Just to make the connection between the `dt` and `dd` elements. But quite right, could cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$('#faq').find('dd:last-child').hide().end().find('dt').click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideDown();
    $(this).siblings('dd').not($(this).next()).slideUp();
});
```

I just added (last:child) class pseudo, because I needed only one to be displayed

thank you, my code gave me a headache, yours is much readable :-D